# Count online user in joomla 3.0

Tags: php, joomla

I am creating a module in joomla 3.0 which will show the list of all online users. but i have no idea that in which database table the status change when any user get online. if any one can help please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In Joomla 3.2.0:**

see file :wwwroot\joomla3.1\administrator\modules\mod_status\mod_status.php 
    (on line:56 you will see the sql to Get the number of frontend logged in users )

```
// Get the number of frontend logged in users.
   $query->clear()
         ->select('COUNT(session_id)')
         ->from('#__session')
         ->where('guest = 0 AND client_id = 0');

   $db->setQuery($query);
   $online_num = (int) $db->loadResult(); # Get the number of frontend logged in users.
```

Comment: ** on line 27 ** : // Get the number of back-end logged in users.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily modify Who’s Online module and get the required data

[You tube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBxEjwZf6L0)